# Control HTML5 video playback within facebook post

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I read the article about [Facebook Now Requires HTML5 and Fallback in Open Graph](http://blog.kaltura.org/facebook-now-require-html5-and-fallback-in-open-graph), and know how to make Facebook recognize the video within the page, and play the video within the post directly.

What I want to do further is do some special control within the post, e.g. start at some given time code, loop playback. Such functionality can be done with `HTML5` video tag + Javascript easily. However, I don't know whether it's possible to do it within the post. I even don't know how to try it.

Do you have any suggestion/comment?

Thanks,

Wesley

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, Facebook will only embed the videos and not any JS code from your site. If they were to embed code it would be a potential security risk for them.